# Oracle: converting a TNS entry with SID to instantclient?

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

How do I convert a TNS entry that has a SID to instantclient format?

I'm able to connect with a TNS string but not with the equivalent (I thought!) instantclient string.

```
$ ./sqlplus 'myname/mypass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.example.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid)))'
Connected to: ...

$ ./sqlplus myname/mypass@//myhost.example.com:1521/mysid

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Comment: You can't specify the SID, but have to specifiy a servicename when using easy connect. `lsnrctl services` on the DB server should tell you, which serivces are available for your database.

Comment: Many thanks!  I can't run lsnrctl, as I'm just on a client machine.  I'll try getting the servicename from the USERENV.

Comment: I'm curious if that will work as you don't connect to a service name. But there's [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399766/how-to-find-oracle-service-name) that gives a solution. Either try on sql*plus `show parameter service_name` or try a `select value from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%';` with another sql client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your working connection that connects using the SID to find which services are in the database. If you are connected run:

```
select name, blocked from v$active_services;
```

and use one of the names you get to connect to.

```
sqlplus myname/mypass@//myhost.example.com:1521/{a name from query}
```